# Azure monitor alert pricing

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have created 120 dynamic log alerts for all instances, and I am a bit unsure of the cost. If i create a dynamic alert for one instance, i am told that it costs roughly 0.20$ dollars a month:

[image]

Here are the rule:
[image]

When I use the Azure calculator i see this:
[image]

I have a hard time figuring out what I am going to pay. It is fine that the creation says 0.20$ and the calculator says 0.10$. If i switch to a static threshold that price is 0.10$. But what about the Log Signals? I am going to calculate that in with my dynamic alert? Or? Does my 120 dynamic alerts include 120 log signals?

I really hope someone here can answer this. It is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the explication of Azure Monitor pricing https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/ you will find following footnote :

> A dynamic alert is billed for the dynamic threshold capability and the underlying metric alert.
>
> Examples
>
> The price of an alert rule which monitors the CPU utilization, and RAM usage (i.e. 2 metric time-series) for 10 VMs, and has dynamic threshold enabled, can be calculated as,
>
> - Price of alert rule + Price of dynamic threshold.
> - (10 VMs * 2 metric
>     time-series per VM – 10 free units) * $0.10 per metric time-series
>     alert rule per month + [(10 VMs * 2 metric time-series per VM) *
>     $0.10 per dynamic threshold per month] = $3 per month.
>
> The price of an alert rule which queries 1 Log analytics workspace for a ‘404-error’ event every 15-minutes can be calculated as,
>
> - 1 workspace * 1 log alert query * $0.50 per log alert rule per month
>     = $0.50 per month.

So, you will pay $0.10 for 1 metric (what you see in Calculator) and + $0.10 for dynamic threshold.

- 1 metric with static threshold costs **$0.10**
- 1 metric with dynamic threshold costs **$0.20** (1 metric $0.10 + 1 dynamic threshold $0.10)
- For 10 firsts metrics you will pay only dynamic threshold which is $0.10, or for 10 firsts with static threshold  **$0.00**

Comment: Ah. So Log signals is something completely different! Thanks.

Comment: @mslot yes, actually you do not have any dynamic threshold additional value in Azure Calculator, it calculates only simple static alerts

Comment: and it is correctly understood that it is 0.20 pr dimension, so if I have a metric that measures  http connections on a serviceplan and I select all dimensions, then it is 0.20 pr instance.